# 503 Server Unavailable in C#

Tags: c#, webclient

So far I have read all the solution provided related to this issue in C#, but unfortunately, none of them working for me.

I am trying to download this image.

http://images.movie25.ag/thumbs/terminator-genisys-2015-59109.jpg

I am using WebClient to do the job, but I am keep on getting this 503 Server Unavailable error.  I tried to navigate the image in Browsers like Chrome, Mozilla, IE, they all are working fine.  Only .Net app is giving me problem for this.

Is there any solution for this problem?

Comment: Copy all request headers from Chrome, they just sniffed out that you are a bot.

Comment: Audrey is right, they know you're a bot. I think they may be running some JS in the browser too (the first visit to the image shows a message about DDOS protection, before displaying the image). They might store a cookie so that the check is unnecessary on subsequent requests.